# scp -r is duplicating last directory

Tags: linux, scp

I have used `scp -r` in the past and I have never seen this.

I am doing the following:

```
dirArr=(
    /drv1/sample1/dataset1
    /drv2/sample2/dataset2
    /drv3/sample3/dataset3
)


for f in ${dirArr[@]}; do
    echo mkdir -p /newdrive3"$f" | ssh user@999.999.999.999 /bin/bash
    scp -r "$f" user@999.999.999.999:"/newdrive3$f"
done
```

The recursive copy happens, but the last directory is duplicated inside itself each time.  So the directory tree structure in the destination is:

```
    /newdrive3/drv1/sample1/dataset1/dataset1
    /newdrive3/drv2/sample2/dataset2/dataset2
    /newdrive3/drv3/sample3/dataset3/dataset3
```

What is causing this?
How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the directories twice.

In your script, use `#! /bin/bash -x` at the top to debug it.

And you only need to create /newdrive3 once.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirArr=(
    /drv1/sample1/dataset1
    /drv2/sample2/dataset2
    /drv3/sample3/dataset3
)

ssh user@999.999.999.999 'mkdir -p /newdrive3'

for f in "${dirArr[@]}"; do
    scp -r "$f" user@999.999.999.999:/newdrive3
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange, and thanks for the answer. Next time, however, please format code as code for better readability. You can use formatting controls in the answer field or [markdown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that.  The reason I did that was I was getting a "No such file or directory" error unless I created the full path directory on the target machine before I used scp to recursively copy into it.

Comment: `sh` doesn't have arrays;, use `bash` for that. So instead of declaring with `#! /bin/sh` you need to use `#! /bin/bash`